# hide child tag inside li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a novice in html/js design. I have searched my specific requirement many ways, but couldn't find a solution. So, your help with a solution via jsfiddle or any example of syntax will be extremely helpful!!!

I have a li element like this in two different div's:

```
<div id="1">
<li> <strong>Song Text</strong><em>Artist</em><var>Lyrics</var></li>
</div>

<div id="2">
<li> <strong>Song Text</strong><em>Artist</em><var>Lyrics</var></li>
</div>
```

As can be seen, li tag comprises of different sub tags(called elements??) like strong, em, var. How do I hide var tag text in first div? i.e., to make it a more generic, how do I **only hide**(not delete) text within a sub-tag in a li tag ? Also, the text needs to be when the page loads, and not by a button click.

Thank you!

Comment: use `$("div#1 li").find("var").hide()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I hide var tag text in first div?

simply try this

```
$("#1 li var").hide();
```

> to make it a more generic, how do I only hide(not delete) text within
>   a sub-tag in a li tag ?

```
$("li").children().hide(); //$("li").children("var").hide(); to hide only var
```

or

```
$("li").find("*").hide();
```

Comment: 1st & 3rd methods do work. Thanks for that. But, #2 hides all children tags within an li - But, I want only a specific tag hidden, so how will that work with children() tag?

Comment: @user3874356 you can do $("li").children("var").hide();

Comment: Gotcha! Also, one more question, if I may: If I have multiple <strong> tags within a single li, how do I hide the nth strong tag....Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @user3874356 you will have to use nth-child selector `$("li:nth-child(2)").hide()`

Comment: I saw about this before, but I couldn't get nth-child to work along with specifying the div type. I'm guessing it should be like $("#2 or #1 li:nth-child(2)").hide()....but doesn't work. Appreciate your patient responses.

Comment: @user3874356 check this doc https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/, share a fiddle of what you have tried

Comment: @user3874356 `$("#2 li *:nth-child(2)").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Like this one?

```js
$('#1 li').find('var').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
<li> test<strong>Song Text</strong><em>Artist</em><var>Lyrics</var></li>
</div>

<div id="2">
<li> test<strong>Song Text</strong><em>Artist</em><var>Lyrics</var></li>
</div>
```